# in SSIS derived column expression to Find last string of excel file name without .xlsx extension

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, substring, ssis-2012

I am creating one SSIS package for that I have requirement to store to Db table only last name of excel file name after underscore (_) and without file extension like .xlsx.

Sample File name : `ddmmmyyyy_HHMM_LabLocation.xlsx`

I found below expression but its displaying like LabLocation.xlsx but I dont want .xlsx extension. Please help me if anyone know how to fix this.

```
RIGHT(@[User::InputFullPath],FINDSTRING(REVERSE(@[User::InputFullPath]),"_",1) - 1)
```

Comment: Any reason for tagging `C#` here? are you looking for solution in C#? I don't think so

Comment: Instead of a derived column you could use a C# task to extract the file name with `var name=Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(...);` , split the string with `var parts=name..Split("_");` and get the last part with `parts.Last()`. You could also use `name.SubString(name.LastIndexOf("_")+1)` to get the last part

Comment: In an expression you can use `TOKEN` and `TOKENCOUNT` to find the last part after a `_`

Answer (score 0):

As .xlsx is constant you can always replace it for empty string:

```
REPLACE(RIGHT(@[User::InputFullPath],FINDSTRING(REVERSE(@[User::InputFullPath]),"_",1) - 1),".xlsx","")
```

if the excel file can also be type ".xls" you can add another replace, surrounding the above